Prove that If $A \subset R^n$ a function $f : A \to R^m$ is continuous iff for every open set $U \in R^m$, $f^{-1}(U) = V \cap A$ for $V$ a open set
($\implies$) direction was easy enough, but I am confused on $(⟸)$. So we have that If $A \subset R^n$, for every open set $U \in R^m$ there is some open set $V \in R^m$ such that $f^{-1}(U) = V \cap A$. This was my idea:
Let $x \in A$. We have that $f(x) \in R^m$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be fixed. It is clear that $B_{\epsilon}(f(x))$ is open and since $B_{\epsilon}(f(x)) \subset R^m$, by hypothesis we have that there exists some open set $V \subset R^n$ such that $f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon}(f(x))) = V \cap A.$ This is where I get stuck. If $A = R^n$ this is quite easy to prove because $V$ is open, but since $V \cap A$ isnt necessarily open, im not sure what to do. From the definition of continuity, I want to find some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $a \in A$ satisfying $ 0 < | x - a | < \delta$ that $ | f(x) - f(a) | < \epsilon$. I was thinking that we could do something with the fact that $f^{-1}(R^m) = (\cup_{a \in A} V_{f(a)}) \cap A$. But im also getting no where with this.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated
Edit: Ok so I realised this can be quite easily done (i think) using the idea of a subspace of a topology, but I am still trying to do it with epsilon and delta

Hint, continuing from where you left off since $V$ open, fix $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta)\subseteq V$, then for all $y\in A$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$, what can you say?

@person Thank you very much! So because we have that $B(x, \delta) \subset V$, we have that for all $y \in A$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ that $y \in B(x, \delta)$ (just restating the definition really) which we know is in V, thus $y \in V$ and since by definition $y \in A$, $y \in V \cap A$ and thus $f(y) \in B(f(x), \epsilon)$, i.e. $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. Nice! Thanks a lot :). If you want to post as an answer Ill accept

See.

Continuing from my hint, since $V$ is open, fix $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta)$ us a subset of $V$. Now if we have any $y \in A$ with $|x-y| <\delta$ we have that $y \in V$, and as such $y \in V \cap A = f^{-1}(B(f(x),\epsilon))$. In other words:
$$|f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon$$
Hence we have found a $\delta$ which works, as required.
